# is there a jquery ui slider for mobile?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am looking for something similar to jquery UI slider, it is not an image slider, it has a handle and slides along a bar. I saw a lot of posts and people were responding with an image rotator which is not what I am looking for. Here is the jquery UI slider http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

This slider is good and it is easy to setup but it does not work for mobile. I don't want to use jquery mobile because my site is a responsive site so when we are on mobile i am not calling in new files.

Is there anything that works for desktop and mobile that is similar to the jquery ui slider?

Answer (score -1):

jQuery Mobile Slider seems like the most obvious choice, no?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/slider/

Comment: I meant use mobile for both desktop and mobile.

Comment: jquery mobile screws up desktop and my site has jquery in it already and cannot be taken out. I found the YUI slider which works for mobile and desktop. but it is a bit slow on android

Answer (score -1):

I've actually made one which we currently use on at work for our mobile pages.  You can check it out here - http://dezignhero.github.io/swiper/

It's designed primarily for webkit devices but also works on desktop too!  Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -3):

You can try refineSlide, it support responsible layout. i used it in my mobile site, you can check out my real world demo here: http://m.gbin1.com

refineslider: http://alexdunphy.github.com/refineslide/

Comment: This is about finding a mobile friendly slider for use as a form element. Take a look at the jquery UI slider in the post for an example.  Your spiny boxy thing is cool, but unrelated.